# Remaking an ambient "glitter" like effect

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am modeling some low poly mushrooms in a cave like area, and I would like to add something like these ambient "glitter" things seen in the image below. (they are probably light reflecting in spores or something.)

[image: Mushrooms with "glitter"]

I think it would be the handiest to add this while rendering randomly but I don't know. Does someone maybe know a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like *Bokeh* ... defocused particles ... just add some *particle system* and for *Camera* enable **Depth of Field** ...

[image]

You can defocus in postproduction (after rendering), but you would have to render a Z-pass (Depth) separately or into OpenEXR Multilayered file format.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser , i will try this when i have time